# How can you open a program in VB.NET program in a folder that is in your programs directory?

Tags: vb.net, file

In my application, I have a program, that is trying to open a program in a folder that is in the same directory as my program. So, it would be \Server\EmilBlockGameServer.exe I am trying to open. With the server folder in the same directory as my launcher. I have tried:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Process.Start("\Server\EmilBlockGameServer.exe")

End Sub
```

But it returns a "File not found" error.

Comment: Can you show us the scheme of the directory?Is the `server` folder is in the `debug` or `release` directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Application.StartupPath` it will return the exact path to your application exe:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Server\EmilBlockGameServer.exe"))
End Sub
```

Depending on your path you might have to remove the `Server\` part of the directory as it is not clear if that was where your exe was or if it was a child directory.

Comment: The server folder is in the same directory as my launcher. The launcher is using a button to launch another program that is in the server folder.

Comment: @EmilSayahi If you found a solution to your problem, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark beside the answer and it will turn green. That will alert everyone else that you are no longer looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm new to asking questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need two backslashes before the server name.

Try `Process.Start("\\Server\EmilBlockGameServer.exe")`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a relative path:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Process.Start(".\Server\EmilBlockGameServer.exe")
End Sub
```

`.\` is the current directory.